# How to print a backspace character with python using repl.it

Tags: python, python-3.x, replit

I am using python3 on repl.it. I was trying to print a backspace but it prints  instead `print("hello\bworld")` should print `hellworld` but it prints `helloworld`. I tried to use `sys.stdout.write("\b")` but it still prints .
Can someone please help?

Comment: Works for me on a normal Linux terminal -- repl.it probably doesn't recognize/respect backspaces and such.

Answer (score 0):

Use `repr`. `repl.it` uses the browser to render the characters. If you compare the number of characters in the output (by using Chrome's JS console, for example), you'll see that `print('abc')` has the same number as `print('a\bc')`.